# Help factorising a sixth degree polynomial

Tags: factoring

I have to factorise- $$x^6+5x^3+8$$Answer is $$(x^2−x+2)(x^4+x^3−x^2+2x+4)$$.I have also used factor theorem.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Make a change of variables $y = x^3$ and factor as you would a quadratic.

Comment: @Nitin-I tried it.But I couldn't do the middle term break after that.

Comment: @Nitin- comes $y^2+5y+8$.It cannot be factorised by middle term breaking after  that.If you can please post an answer.

Comment: @Nitin-It is factorable.Answer as in wolfram alpha is $(x^2-x+2)(x^4+x^3-x^2+2x+4)$.Now I also tried to use factor theorem.

Comment: @Nitin-It is also useless to use quadratic formula to find the roots as $4ac$ is greater than $b^2$ (part under the square root).So the root would be coming complex.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the equation $x^6+5x^3+8$ into $x^6+8-x^3+6x^3$. It then comes into the form $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$. Factorise it using the formula $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$.

Answer (score 4):

It can be factored with help of following identities (applied twice below, marked by a '*')

$$u^3 \pm v^3 = (u \pm v)(u^2 \pm uv + v^2)$$

Let $u = x^2 + 2$, we have

$$\begin{align}
x^6 + 5x^3 + 8 
&= (x^2)^3 + 2^3 + 5x^3\tag{1}\\
&\stackrel{*}{=} (x^2+2)(x^4 - 2x^2 + 4) + 5x^3\\
&= u(u^2 - 6x^2) + 5x^3\tag{2}\\
&= (u^3 - x^3) - 6x^2(u-x)\\
&\stackrel{*}{=} (u-x)(u^2 + ux + x^2 - 6x^2)\\
&= (x^2 - x + 2)((x^2 + 2)^2 + x(x^2+2) - 5x^2)\\
&= (x^2 - x + 2)(x^4 + x^3 - x^2 + 2x + 4)
\end{align}
$$
**Rationale behind the steps**

- The motivation for step 1 is the non-zero coefficients of $x^k$ are symmetric
  around $k = 3$ term. i.e
  $$x^6 + 5x^3 + 8 = x^3 \left(x^3 + 5 + \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^3\right)$$
  I try to express everything in terms of $x + \frac{2}{x}$ and looks for simplification.
- Some where in the process, I notice the $1, -6, 5$ pattern in some
  expression equivalent to $(2)$. This implies the existence of a factor $u - x$
  in the original expression. The rest is more or less following the nose.