# How can I factor $x^6+5x^3+8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, factoring

$$x^6 + 5 x^3 + 8$$
I have tried to solve this by some middle term fact, but have failed and I **think** these are useless in this sum. Please help me.
(**Not a P.S.Q.**)

Comment: Treat $x^3$ as an unknown in itself, call it $t$ if you like. The resulting $t^2+5t+8$ can be factored, but only with the help of the Quadratic Formula.

Comment: Why do you think it can be factored?

Comment: This doesn't have any real roots, but you can factor it into a quadratic and a quartic $(x^2 - x + 2)(x^4 + x^3 - x^2 + 2x + 4)$.

Comment: Thank you, but will you please explain(to Alexis))

Comment: wolfram alpha :)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorise+(x%5E6%2B5x%5E3%2B8)

Comment: I don't want the ans. sir. I need the explanation.(z100 and momo)

Comment: Ok, then Google: "factorize x^6+5x^3+8" and see one of the hits e.g. this one: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-factorize-x-6+5x-3+8  or the same question on SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432223/factor-x6-5x3-8/432240

Comment: What's to explain?  They plugged it into a computer and the computer spit out the answer by trying all possibilities.  If you want to try it be hand try all for possibilities.

Comment: Can you find the roots using Lubin's hint?

Comment: you may want to look at this.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a truly fiendish problem, well suited to Hallowe’en tide.

Set $t=x^3$, to get $t^2+5t+8=0$, whose roots are $(-5\pm\sqrt{-7})/2$. Now, the integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-7}\,)$ are a unique factorization domain, in which
$$2=\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}2\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}2\,.$$
The number $(-5+\sqrt{-7})/2$ has Norm $8$, of course, that’s the constant term in its minimal polynomial. So you can hope that $t=(-5+\sqrt{-7})/2$ actually is a cube. Indeed, it’s equal to $\bigl[(1-\sqrt{-7}\,)/2\bigr]^3$. So we find that $(1+\sqrt{-7})/2$ is a root, and so $x^2-x+2$ is a factor of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: $\,x=0\,$ is not a root, so dividing by $\,x \ne 0\,$ gives $\displaystyle\,x^3+\frac{8}{x^3}=-5\,$.

Let $\displaystyle\, z = x + \frac{2}{x}\,$, then $\displaystyle\,z^3 = x^3 + \frac{8}{x^3}+6z\,=6z -5 \;\implies\, z^3 - 6z + 5 = 0$. The latter has the obvious root $\,z=1\,$, so the original polynomial has a factor $\displaystyle\,x \cdot \left(x + \frac{2}{x}-1\right)=x^2-x+2\,$.

Comment: A useful trick. Not guaranteed to produce a factor, of course. But if it works :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, and right. It's long been my suspicion that problem writers know a thing or two about reciprocal polynomials themselves ;-)